# Can not get Google auth header after google signin (Null check operator used on a null value)

Tags: firebase, flutter, oauth, google-api, google-signin

I can get an auth header during google signing but when I tried to get the auth header after signing, it shows me this message `Null check operator used on a null value`.

```
var googleUser = GoogleSignIn(scopes: [drive.DriveApi.driveScope]);
var _header = await googleUser.currentUser!.authHeaders;
```